# How to embed the MIDAS.DLL in the client executable

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, datasnap

According to dr. Bob it can be done. Can someone provide step by step example or some tutorial?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't embed MIDAS.DLL; you add `MidasLib` to your project's **USES** clause.  This embeds the basic functionality into your program without having to rely on a separate DLL for it.

Comment: Besides this is really simple, there is an article explaining in EDN: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29297